# TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 5 were given

Tags: python, databases

I got this positional argument error. Here is the code that I copy from other sources.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [15], in <cell line: 3>()
      1 ############### CONFIGURE THIS ###################
      2 # Open database connection
----> 3 db = pymysql.connect("localhost","sql8510682","6huzgCC7q3","sql8510682")

TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 5 were given
```

Answer (score 0):

Try naming arguments, from the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/PyMySQL/), it should work (of course, adapt your values):

```
import pymysql

# Connect to the database
connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                             user='user',
                             password='passwd',
                             database='db',
                             charset='utf8mb4',
                             cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
```